# How to store log parameters in a 2D array

Tags: java, html

I have a string in Java-

```
parameter1 => yes
parameter2 => yes
parameter3 => Tom
parameter4 => log4
parameter5 => 04/20/2011:15:23:21
parameter6 => 500
parameter7 => [DAILY, MTD, BIMTD]
```

Now how do I save the parameter-value pairs in a 2D array ? I need to show the parameter-value pairs in a HTML page as a table, one column containing the parameter name and the other column containing the value.

Comment: What would the two dimensions be? I can only see one dimension here: parameter1..7

Comment: Use the String split method and you will get the array of strings - as one way.  It will work for a simple string values.

Comment: @biziclop dimension1=name of parameter(i.e 1..7) , dimension2=value of parameter(i.e. yes,yes,Tom,etc)

Comment: @muruga How do I apply split to each pair as what I've pasted above is a single big string ?

Comment: @kaustav-datta , what is your big string look like?

Answer (score 1):

Keeping all these 7 parameters as fields of a custom class and then using an array of instances of that class would be far more easier to implement.

```
class Custom
{
   String param1, param2, ...
   // String[] params => you can also store parameters in an array.

}

Custom[] array = new Custom[50];
```

Answer (score 0):

From the clues you gave, I believe a HashMap (pairs of key, value) can be considered as an approach.

Comment: Hmm ya, but what I have is a single big string, so how do I split each line and put them in HashMap ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Map.

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
//Populate the map
map.put("ParamName", "ParamValue");
...


//Iterate on the values
for (Entry e : map) {
  System.out.println("Param " +  e.getKey() + " Value " + e.getValue()); 
}
```